# Is the object necessary in “It teaches (all) to think”?

Tags: meaning, direct-objects

What are the differences between:

> 1. It teaches to think.

> 2. It teaches all to think.

I have found in a book that the 1st sentence isn’t correct. Is that right?

Comment: What book were you using? What do you think the sentences mean?

Comment: I am using an admission preparation book(Bangladesh)   .I think both sentences are right.@KillingTime

Comment: (1) is not far off being incorrect, ungrammatical, irredemable. Except perhaps as an extraposition of 'To think teaches'. Compare _It helps to remember that there have always been times like the present._ But totally unidiomatic. // 'It teaches all to think' is more acceptable, with a semi-referential 'it' this time, but 'How frail we are is made very clear in such circumstances. It teaches us all to think' is more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks to Laurel for editing to provide what many here were thinking. The construction _It teaches thinking_ would probably be acceptable, but can the infinitive _to think_  be thought of as an object?

Comment: I can't think of any contexts where it's idiomatic to say *[Subject] **teaches** [infinitive verb]*. I'm fine with a continuous participle / gerund, as in ***This book*** (or, *"**It**"*) *teaches **thinking***, but not ***...to think.***

Comment: While there may be a case where 1 can be grammatical, it does not mean anything like 2.  For OP’s purpose where the intended meaning is 2.  1 is ungrammatical.     Incidentally, think where 1 becomes grammatical is when it follows the same form as:  “It soothes to itch.”

Comment: The first example seems to be saying that "it" can't think unless it's teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of construction seems uncertain and this [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/551259/is-the-object-necessary-in-it-teaches-all-to-think#comment1357241_551259) (**user Edwin Ashworth**) provides clues in explaining that this is so.

Here is an instance of what this user refers to in the way of justifying this construction, although the verb has a complement.

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=dqUjfDr30L0C&pg=PA30&dq=%22it+teaches+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTrJfZiPbsAhWKDxQKHRCKB4kQ6AEwEnoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22it%20teaches%20to%22&f=false)) "it teaches to read well, that is to say, to read slowly, deeply, looking cautiously before and aft, with reservations, with doors left open, with delicate eyes and fingers"

As a fact,  this construction does not occur much; I found one instance in Google Books.

([ref. 1,](https://books.google.fr/books?id=2XqFzGOlzagC&pg=PA364&dq=%22it+teaches+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTrJfZiPbsAhWKDxQKHRCKB4kQ6AEwHnoECDsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22it%20teaches%20to%22&f=false) ) “it teaches to dance”

However, there occurs an important number of cases where the verb has a complement or an adjunct.

([ref. 1, 1870](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8BUTBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22it+teaches+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTrJfZiPbsAhWKDxQKHRCKB4kQ6AEwSHoECD4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22it%20teaches%20to%22&f=false)) It teaches to avoid labor, to avoid solitude, and to evade ...

([ref. 2, 2010](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZScxLdr2mDgC&pg=PT334&dq=%22it+teaches+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTrJfZiPbsAhWKDxQKHRCKB4kQ6AEwSXoECCMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22it%20teaches%20to%22&f=false))  it teaches to be good.

([ref. 3, 1980](https://books.google.fr/books?id=wnI3AAAAIAAJ&q=%22it+teaches+to%22&dq=%22it+teaches+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTrJfZiPbsAhWKDxQKHRCKB4kQ6AEwUnoECCEQAg))  it teaches to see light,

So, it seems to me that a slight modification in the construction of the verb phrase makes it acceptable, which is not to say that there should be a possibility to preserve the plain meaning of the verb that way.

- it teaches to think truly/well/swiftly/…

---

The simplest means to establish that construction on firm ground seems to be the introduction of the pronoun "one". There are a few recorded cases of such a usage.

([ref. 1, 2001](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Uy5r9xM9P7YC&pg=PA105&dq=%22it+teaches+one+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCqN7rhfbsAhXExYUKHcJWBwYQ6AEwAXoECE0QAg#v=onepage&q=%22it%20teaches%20one%20to%22&f=false)) It teaches one who they are, it teaches one to discern, it teaches one self reliance,

([ref. 2, 2004](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8jUEAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA231&dq=%22it+teaches+one+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCqN7rhfbsAhXExYUKHcJWBwYQ6AEwGHoECCwQAg#v=onepage&q=%22it%20teaches%20one%20to%22&f=false)) It teaches one to give and take

([ref.3, 1831](https://books.google.fr/books?id=rq1OAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA2-PA626&dq=%22it+teaches+one+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCqN7rhfbsAhXExYUKHcJWBwYQ6AEwG3oECDIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22it%20teaches%20one%20to%22&f=false)) Unless it teaches one to quote and cavil ?

([ref. 4, 201
1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=6k8RYd5C-7oC&pg=PT313&dq=%22it+teaches+one+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCqN7rhfbsAhXExYUKHcJWBwYQ6AEwHHoECDQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22it%20teaches%20one%20to%22&f=false)) It teaches one to grow up.